# Java: Unmapped target properties

Tags: java, maven, mapper, mapstruct

I have a problem with Mapper.I am using a mapstruct-processor to build Maven project. All time I get a warning: 
Warning:(15, 16) java: Unmapped target properties: "from, to".
Warning:(13, 13) java: Unmapped target properties: "clientFrom, clientTo".
What did I suppose to do with that?  Class Client works well and creates a Client.

```
 @Entity
public class Message {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String message;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "client_from")
private Client clientFrom;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "client_to")
private Client clientTo;

public Message(){}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Client getClientFrom() {
    return clientFrom;
}

public void setClientFrom(Client clientFrom) {
    this.clientFrom = clientFrom;
}

public Client getClientTo() {
    return clientTo;
}

public void setClientTo(Client clientTo) {
    this.clientTo = clientTo;
}


}


public class MessageDTO {

private Long id;
private String message;
private ClientDTO from;
private ClientDTO to;

public MessageDTO(){}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public ClientDTO getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(ClientDTO from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public ClientDTO getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(ClientDTO to) {
    this.to = to;
}
}



 @Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {ClientMapper.class})
public interface MessageMapper {

Message toMessage(MessageDTO messageDTO);

MessageDTO toMessageDTO(Message message);

List<Message> toMessageList(List<MessageDTO> list);
List<MessageDTO> toMessageDTOList(List<Message> list);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error `Unmapped target properties: "<list of properties>"` is usually represented on the appropriate methods and in your case it means that MapStruct could not find `from` and `to` for the mapping of `MessageDTO toMessageDTO(Message message)` and `clientFrom` and `clientTo` for the mapping of `Message toMessage(MessageDTO messageDTO)`.

To solve this you will have to explicitly define the mappings between the different properties.

Your mapper will look like (I am assuming `mapstruct-jdk8` usage):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {ClientMapper.class})
public interface MessageMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "clientFrom", source = "from")
    @Mapping(target = "clientTo", source = "to")
    Message toMessage(MessageDTO messageDTO);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration //MapStruct will automatically reverse the defined mappings from toMessage
    MessageDTO toMessageDTO(Message message);

    List<Message> toMessageList(List<MessageDTO> list);
    List<MessageDTO> toMessageDTOList(List<Message> list);
}
```

For better understanding have a look at [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#basic-mappings). In the documentation. For more info about the `@InheritInverseConfiguration` have a look [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#inverse-mappings).

If the names of the properties (getters / setters) were the same in `Message` and `MessageDTO`, then you wouldn't need the `@Mapping` annotations

Answer (score 29):

In the latest versions of `MapStruct` you can:

1. Define `@Mapping` annotation with `ignore=true` attribute for any field that should not be mapped OR
2. Add special reporting policy to your mapper interface to suppress warnings on all unmapped fields at once, like this:

```java
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
```